# How to do bindings from Interface Builder with custom control?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, custom-controls

If I want to bind to properties of my custom control from Interface Builder do I need to write my own IB plugin? Will I have to do it programmatically otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write an IB Plugin and expose the control's bindings if you want to establish bindings in Interface Builder. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605721/binding-a-custom-nsview-does-it-demand-creating-an-ibplugin/607906#607906) to a similar question.